# shell create new directory and check whether it exists

Tags: bash, shell

the file have many lines, each lines contain

int folder-name file-path    file-path    file-path

eg.

```
1001    AS35_59328      RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93     /ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T1
1073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS35_59328/111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IP
AAPEK-93_1.fq.gz        /ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS35_5932
8/111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_2.fq.gz  
/ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS35_5932
8/111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-9322121_2.fq.gz
```

so how can i get the folder name( AS35_59328 ) and create folder if it is not created.

get the line second section AS35_59328, if the  AS35_59328 has already exist, put all files in the line into folder, else create  AS35_59328 folder then put files into

Comment: Can you explain your question little more bit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another purely shell solution:

```
while read line; do
  set $line
  key=$1; shift
  dir=$1; shift
  test -d $dir || mkdir $dir
  mv $@ $dir
done < myfile.txt

    bll-laptop:bll$ cat t.sh
    #!/bin/bash

    cat > myfile.txt << _HERE_
    1001 d1 a b c
    1002 d2 d e f
    1003 d3 g h i
    _HERE_

    touch a b c d e f g h i
    rm -rf d1 d2 d2 > /dev/null 2>&1
    mkdir d1

    while read line; do
      set $line
      key=$1; shift
      dir=$1; shift
      test -d $dir || mkdir $dir
      mv $@ $dir
    done < myfile.txt

    ls -R

    bll-laptop:bll$ ./t.sh
    .:
    d1  d2  d3  myfile.txt  t.sh

    ./d1:
    a  b  c

    ./d2:
    d  e  f

    ./d3:
    g  h  i
    bll-laptop:bll$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat stack.txt 
1001    AS35_59328      RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93     /ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T1
1073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS35_59328/111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IP
AAPEK-93_1.fq.gz        /ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS35_5932
8/111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_2.fq.gz  
/ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS35_5932
8/111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-9322121_2.fq.gz


$for j in $(for i in `cat stack.txt | tr '\n' '\0' | grep -a -o '/.*gz'`; do echo $i ;     done | awk -F\/ '{ print $NF }'); do echo $j ; done
111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_1.fq.gz
111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_2.fq.gz
111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-9322121_2.fq.g
```

**Final oneliner:**

This one liner will help you to fetch all file names and then it will copy all those fetched file names to `AS35_59328`. If `AS35_59328` is not exists, it will create such a directory and then it will put all those files into it.

```
if [ -d "AS35_59328"]; then for j in $(for i in `cat stack.txt | tr '\n' '\0' | grep -a -o '/.*gz'`; do echo $i ; done | awk -F\/ '{ print $NF }'); do cp -v $j AS35_59328/ ; done ; else for j in $(for i in `cat stack.txt | tr '\n' '\0' | grep -a -o '/.*gz'`; do echo $i ; done | awk -F\/ '{ print $NF }'); do mkdir AS35_59328 && cp -v $j AS35_59328/ ; fi
```